# Save Data from Fragment in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, save, onsaveinstancestate

Save the the Data from Fragment in a Activity won't work

Setup: I have 2 Activies with 2 Fragments which are dynamical created

Activity Main contains both Fragments when in Landscape Modus,
else only Fragment Main and starts Activity Edit by ActivityForResult

Activity Edit contains Fragment Edit

The Activity Main has a Database

Fragment Main gets a List from the Activity

Fragment Edit modifies the List

My approach is to save the list in the Activity when Fragment Main, containing the List, is destroyed.

Current status
Data is not written to the Database when ActivityForResult is called 
and also not when in Landscape mode.

What confuses me is that Data is written when the Display is turned, but i don't update the list in the MainActivity at any point

```
 MainActivity 
================
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        getTable() // gets Data from DataBase

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.frame_main, MainFragment.newInstance(dbList, true), "mainFragment")
                .commit()

        } else {
            // Destroys the Fragment because I want to load it with different config
            var  mainFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("mainFragment") as MainFragment
            mainFragment.onDestroyView()
            // Checks if it is Landscape
            if (TabletHelper.isLandscape(this)) {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                    R.id.frame_main,
                    MainFragment.newInstance(dbList, false),
                    "mainFragment"
                ).commit()
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                    R.id.frame_edit,
                    EditFragment.newInstance(null, null, true, null),
                    "editFragment"
                ).commit()
            } else {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
                    R.id.frame_main,
                    MainFragment.newInstance(dbList, true),
                    "mainFragment"
                ).commit()
            }
        }

    }

// interface implementation from the MainFragment
    override fun passList(list: ArrayList<Product>) {
        dbList.clear()
        dbList.addAll(list)
    }
// Write the list to the DataBase
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        productsDBHelper.writeAllProducts(dbList, TABLE_NAME_MAIN)
    }


}

 MainFragment
==============
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        if(savedInstanceState != null && savedState == null) {
            savedState = savedInstanceState.getBundle(BUNDLE)
        }
        if(savedState != null) {
            productList.addAll(savedState!!.getParcelableArrayList<Product>(PRODUCT_LIST_KEY)!!)
        }
        savedState = null

 //doing something with Layout...

        }
    }
// save bundel when onDestroyView is called 
   override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        savedState = saveState()

    }
// Interface to pass the data to the Activity
    interface  OnFragmentMainClicked {
        fun passList(list: ArrayList<Product>)
    //..

    }


//creating Bundle for instance
    private fun saveState():Bundle{
        var state = Bundle()
        state.putParcelableArrayList(PRODUCT_LIST_KEY,productList)
        return state
    }
// Save Instance
    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        if (savedState != null ){
            outState.putBundle(BUNDLE,savedState)
        }else{
            outState.putBundle(BUNDLE,saveState())
        }
    }









//My Thought was to save the Data always when when onDestroyView in the Fragment is called
     override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        savedState = saveState()
        onFragmentMainClicked.passList(productList)
    }
//But it is not working. Result is that it clears whole list
```

Comment: Use `interface` as the communicator between Activities and fragments. This practice is pretty good for development.

Comment: I updated the code. I am using a interface, but when to use it and why is the list updated when i turn the display. Btw thx for your response

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are setting your list in `onDestroyView()` at the first place. Steps to communicate if you you want this list until activity is alive. So, to achieve this create another method to get your list `getList()` inside your interface, which will return your list. As you have to implement both `passList(list: List<Type>)` and `getList(): List<Type>`. Now, take a list object globally in your activity, populate into your `passList(list)` method and return global list object (which is already populated). 
Then simply call the `getList()` with the interface object. I hope you will get your list by using the interface.
Hope it helps. Let me know.

Comment: Hey i fixed the problem, but i don't why it works like this. The list in the Activity which I pass as a ParcelableArrayList to the Fragment, is always updated when i do some modification in the Fragment. In the Activity now i always write in onPause the list to my database , so that no changes in the List of the Activity  are lost. So the interface was not needed in my case, but thx a lot for your thoughts. Maybe u can explain me why the List I pass to the Fragment by the Arguments also overwrite the List in the Activity.